# How to animate moving each text -30deg

Tags: html, css

I have a Problem that my text is moving x-direction instead of 30deg. I need to move the text 30deg along. I use `transform: rotate (30deg)` and I create keyframe animation on  start `transformX:100%` and set end `transformX=-100%` but its not working.
[SCreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0MDX.jpg)

```css
section{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 130%;
    overflow: hidden;    }
section .type-text{
 
    display: flex;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow: hidden; 
    animation: animate 80s linear infinite; }}
ul{transform: rotate(-30deg);}
`@keyframes animate {

0%{
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
100%{
    transform: translateX(-100%);


}
   
}
section .animating{
animation: animate 10s linear infinite;`
```

```html
<body>   
    <section class="type-hover">
        <div id="anime" class="animating">
        <ul class="type-text">
            <li>Happy</li>
            <li>Birthday</li>
            <li>Angela</li>
            <li>Moshi</li>
            <li>Happy</li>
            <li>Birthday</li>
            <li>Angela</li>
            <li>Moshi</li> <li>Happy</li>
            <li>Birthday</li>
            <li>Angela</li>
            <li>Moshi</li>
            <li>Happy</li>
            <li>Birthday</li>
            <li>Angela</li>
            <li>Moshi</li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
>there are more ul(s)

</section>
```

Comment: You have a typo in your styles, two right braces before the ul instead of one. So your ul setting is ignored. Using a CSS validator can help find this sort of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant add two transform to same element `(ul,type-text)` although you can chain many to same transform tag .I dont understood exactly what you end goal is but if you want rotated div with moving text here's an example.

```css
section{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 130%;
    overflow: hidden;    }
section .type-text{
 
    display: flex;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow: hidden; 
    animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}
/* ul{transform: rotate(-30deg);} */

@keyframes animate {
  0%   {transform: translateX(100%) rotate(-30deg);}
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-30deg)}
}
```

```html
 <section class="type-hover">
        <div id="anime" class="animating">
        <ul class="type-text">
            <li>Happy</li>
            <li>Birthday</li>
            <li>Angela</li>
            <li>Moshi</li>
            <li>Happy</li>
            <li>Birthday</li>
            <li>Angela</li>
            <li>Moshi</li> <li>Happy</li>
            <li>Birthday</li>
            <li>Angela</li>
            <li>Moshi</li>
            <li>Happy</li>
            <li>Birthday</li>
            <li>Angela</li>
            <li>Moshi</li>
        </ul>
          
          
          
    </div> 

</section>
```